# How to pass a logger message value to .xslt file in mule

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, wsdl, mule

In configuration.xml file I implemented a flow for publishing out a wsdl, during the way I put a logger that return Client's IP address. this is my code:

```
<logger message="#[groovy:message.getInboundProperty('MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS')]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Now I want to transfer(pass) ip address to my .xslt file? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Mule 3.3, you can utilize [MEL](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Mule+Expression+Language) and simplify logger statement like this:

```
<logger message="#[message.inboundProperties['MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

To pass IP address to XSLT, store it in a variable and pass that.

```
<set-variable variableName="remoteClientAddress" value = "#[message.inboundProperties['MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS']]"/>
```

Display with logger

```
  <logger message="Remote client address is------> #[remoteClientAddress]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Pass it to `XSLT` as:

```
   <xm:xslt-transformer xsl-file="xsltFileName.xslt">
        <xm:context-property key="remoteClientAddress" value="#[remoteClientAddress]"/>
    </xm:xslt-transformer>
```

In your `XSLT`, declare a param variable

```
<xsl:param  name="remoteClientAddress" />
```

and then use this variable as

```
<xsl:value-of select="$remoteClientAddress" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my $remoteClientAddress format is like this : /127.0.0.1:51708  how can I omit / before ip address and :51708 from the end of my string?

Comment: You may want to post it as separate question describing in detail.

Comment: Use String processors in XSLT

Answer (score 0):

For the problem related to extracting you IP address properly use XSLT functions like

```
 substring-before() , substring-after()  and tokenize() ( in XSLT 2.0)
```